# Using powershell with c# namespace error

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-assembly

I'am trying to use (remote) powershell from c#.

I use :

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspace;
```

But when I try to build my app I have an error CS0234 (name does not exist in the namespace). I have added the reference of System.Management.

Which way to compile ?

Ps : I find a post where they said to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` as a reference but I don't have this path...

PPs : Powershell is fully installed on my computer.

PPPs : Using win10 64 bits

Comment: have you even searched for that directory? aka the windowspowershell\1.0

Comment: Add reference and browse...go to that path (it can be 3.0 or 1.0) and select System.Management.Automation.dll

Comment: btw that path would appear to be true for 64bit win7 ...

Answer (score 2):

After searching and searching I finally find this file on my machine :

```
C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll
```

Which is the one for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Nuget package to add the references:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies/

Answer (score 0):

Runspace is the class. Use only:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
```

And add reference to:

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll